# Repair broken button from dishwasher controller plastic case

Tags: repair, dishwasher, plastic

So recently my dishwasher stopped working.

After disassembling, I found out that the problem was just the on/off button. It won't work because when you press it, it pushes a plastic piece that is broken. There are 4 buttons (1 and 3) in the picture. The one broken is the one to the left by itself.

It's a very small problem, but a replacement is expensive because you have to buy the entire piece with the circuit included. Any idea on how to fix this?

Here's a picture of a new plastic case:

[image: Fagor 2LF-013SX]

And here mine with the left button plastic piece missing:

[image: My Fagor 2LF-013SX]

Comment: Any idea _how_ yours broke?  Where it's broken?  That's going to make a difference on how it gets fixed.

Comment: Can you post photos? One possibility might be to remove anything that is still left from the broken button and operate it with a pencil in the future ;)

Comment: @JPhi1618 the plastic piece is held to the entire structure by 2 tiny pieces (it ca be better seen in the first one from the set of 3 on the right side) and theres where the button broke, so now that piece is "detached".
(at)Jasper I dont have it at the moment, but as said before, there 2 pieces that help it in place broke, so now theres just the hole.

Comment: If you can find the broken piece, try something like what is done here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWGGcxqdA84 (basically make a hinge out of hot glue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried looking for a secondhand part? Or a similar model dead from pump failure etc. 
Our plastic handle/fascia broke. £70 for new one. Taped it up then put a search on a well known auction site. After a few months the part turned up for £15 all in.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never came up with secondhand parts, I was just trying to find a replacement, but the original one is like 80€. Right now I just quickly google it, and found another model, but the controller seems to match! :D 
http://mimgs.sgmn.es/635x476/813/81333141996.jpg

Comment: I couldn't see the make if yours. Mine was Bosch & I was able to cross-reference parts from a different model as they have good exploded diagrams.  I found the part number of the bit I needed then getting the part number of the apparently similar part on ebay. Many retailers as provided the manufacturers part numbers. In the end there may be a small amount of risk: only you can accept that. Also bear in mind that the same model may come in a different colour and have a (slightly) different number but be functionally the same.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the switch pushes the plastic piece until it makes a PC board microswitch behind it.

You need to figure out a way to attach something to the switch that would make the microswitch when you push the button. OR Attach something to the platic case that will bend like the plastic to make the switch.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yeah, that's what it does, but I couldnt phrase it properly (not native english speaker). The ideal thing would be to reattach the broken plastic piece, but didnt come up with a way to do so, thats why I came here to ask